# Handle HTTP Request with Subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, http, subscribe

I have a provider with the method `call()` which I use for the `http.post()` request. My aim is to handle inside the `call()` the check if the object contains `permission_deny` or `error` and handle this already within the `call()`. As well if no connection to the server, should be already handled inside the method `call()`. I just want to return to the component, when the JSON passes any of the above checks. But I have no idea, how I can handle this. Here my current state, but I'm aware this can't work with `.subscribe()` in the component.

**Any Component**

```
buttonTest(){ 
   let params = new URLSearchParams();
   this.dataService.call('clasABC, 'methodABC', params).subscribe((data) => {

      // Handle data

   });
}
```

**Provider**

```
public call(class, method, params: URLSearchParams) {

    params.set('c', class); 
    params.set('m', method);

    this.http.post(/* URI CALL */)
      .subscribe((data)=> {
         try {
            var jsonDataObject = JSON.parse(data.text());

            if (jsonDataObject.hasOwnProperty('permission_deny'))
            {

              // Show alert
              return  null;

            } else if (jsonDataObject.hasOwnProperty('error'))
            {

              // Show alert 
              return  null;
            }

            return jsonDataObject;

            } catch (e)
            {
                console.log(e);
            }

          }, (error) => {

            // Alert 

          })
      }
```

Comment: Actually, you *need* the subscribe within the component, otherwise the component will have no way of knowing when the HTTP call has responded. In your `call` function, change from `subscribe` to `map`, and put a `return` just before `this.http`. This will allow the `call` function to modify the response, and pass it on. (Also, using `data.text()` implies you're using `Http` instead of `HttpClient`. We shouldn't be using the `Http` class any more because it's deprecated. And using `.text()`, along with `JSON.parse` is odd. Why not just use `.json()`?)

Comment: Yea, I exactly did that before. return before `this.http` and handle everything in the component class. But in that case, i have to write every time the handles which i did above with permission_deny, error … . I'm not sure, when jusing directly `.json()` , im not sure that I receive any time a json object.

Comment: do the error cheking on the observable of httpcall by pipeng and mapping

Comment: You can handle it in `map` within the `call` function if you use `map`

Comment: That's a nice idea, im gonna try it out.

Comment: But what is the proper way to check in the component class if it's an json object?

Comment: Do you not know up front whether your endpoint returns JSON?

Comment: Actually it should, but i cant 100% guarentee it. So I guess i have also parse it again and handling when error occurs?

Comment: Use `data.json()` in the `map` function, which will do the same as `JSON.parse`. You can add error handling in there as well if you need. That way the component doesn't need to worry.